# How do I edit tableview cell on numeric key release and have the key that is pressed put into the TextFieldTableCell?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Good Day

When on an editable cell, I would like the user to start typing a number without having to press the Enter key first. I have this partly working with the following code :

```
    tableView.setEditable(true);
    tableView.getSelectionModel().cellSelectionEnabledProperty().set(true);

    tableView.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            TablePosition tp;
            if(event.getCode().isDigitKey()){
                tp = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
                tableView.edit(tp.getRow() , tp.getTableColumn());
            }

        }
    });

    setColumnStyling();

    updateOrderColumn.setMaxWidth(1500);
    updateOrderColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));
    updateOrderColumn.setEditable(true);
```

As soon as a Numeric key is press, the cell does go into editing mode. However, the Numeric key that is initially pressed is not entered into the TextFieldTableCell. Therefor if the user types "1234", only "234" is captured.

How do I overcome this?
I could save the key press to a String variable, but then how do I insert it into the cell?

Comment: move the handler into a custom cell (extend TextFieldTableCell), let it call startEdit when detecting the keyPressed of a digit - the following keyReleased/keytyped should be enough to insert the code.

Comment: hmm ... that's weird: the cell doesn't receive any keys, at least not when it is selected/focused - only if the focus is .. elsewhere? Don't quite understand what's going on, might be a bug (or related to the wretched focus/edit handling of cells ..)

Comment: Yip, the cell doesn't receive any keys. Thought maybe calling setOnEditStart() on the cell and somehow passing it the original key press might help but it doesn't. No luck with overriding startEdit() either.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do with the standard `TextFieldTableCell` you get from
`TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()`, but you can create a custom table cell like this:

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class CustomTableCellTestApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<Item> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        TableColumn<Item, Integer> intCol = new TableColumn<>("int col");
        tableView.getColumns().add(intCol);
        intCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().myIntProperty().asObject());
        intCol.setCellFactory(c -> new CustomTableCell());
        intCol.setMinWidth(150);

        // Enter edit mode on digit key pressed:
        tableView.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            TablePosition<Item, ?> pos = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
            if (pos != null && event.getCode().isDigitKey())
                tableView.edit(pos.getRow(), pos.getTableColumn());
        });

        IntStream.range(23, 28).forEach(i -> tableView.getItems().add(new Item(i)));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
        stage.show();
    }

    class CustomTableCell extends TableCell<Item, Integer> {
        private TextField textField;

        boolean initValue;

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getItem().toString());

            // This fixes "initially pressed [digit] is not entered into the TextFieldTableCell"
            initValue = false;
            textField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyEvent -> {
                if (!initValue && !(keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                    textField.setText(keyEvent.getText());
                    textField.positionCaret(textField.getText().length());
                }
                initValue = true;
            });

            textField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    try {
                        commitEdit(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    } finally {
                        keyEvent.consume();
                    }
                }
            });

            // Commit value on focus lost:
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                if (wasFocused) {
                    try {
                        commitEdit(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                }
            });

            // Allow only ten digits:
            textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
                String text = change.getControlNewText();
                if (text.matches("\\d*") && text.length() < 10)
                    return change;
                return null;
            }));
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            setText(null);
            createTextField();
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.requestFocus();
            textField.selectAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(getItem().toString());
            setGraphic(null);
            textField = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void commitEdit(Integer item) {
            // This block is necessary to support commit on losing focus, because the baked-in mechanism
            // sets our editing state to false before we can intercept the loss of focus.
            // The default commitEdit(...) method simply bails if we are not editing...
            // See: https://gist.github.com/james-d/be5bbd6255a4640a5357
            if (!isEditing() && !item.equals(getItem())) {
                TableView<Item> table = getTableView();
                if (table != null) {
                    TableColumn<Item, Integer> column = getTableColumn();
                    TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Item, Integer> event = new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(table,
                            new TablePosition<>(table, getIndex(), column), TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), item);
                    Event.fireEvent(column, event);
                }
            }
            super.commitEdit(item);
            setText(item.toString());
            setGraphic(null);
            textField = null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty)
                setText(null);
            else
                setText(item.toString());
        }
    }

    class Item {

        private final IntegerProperty myInt;

        public Item(int age) {
            this.myInt = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
        }

        public int getMyInt() {
            return myInt.get();
        }

        public IntegerProperty myIntProperty() {
            return myInt;
        }

        public void setMyInt(int myInt) {
            this.myInt.set(myInt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem with this code, enter 12 quickly and the cell will only contain 1. The code can be changed to prepend the first key instead of setting it. But this introduces another problem, if the cell has content before being edited, then the typed value will prepend instead of overwriting existing value. Tricky one.

Comment: It happens when the second key is pressed before the first key has been released. Please share a better solution if you find one and I can delete mine. Greetings.

Comment: Remove the KEY_RELEASED handler entirely. Then add textField.applyCss() between textField.requestFocus() and textField.selectAll() inside startEdit. Works for me!